# Native American (possibly) apocalyptic prophecy about inanimate objects coming to life

Tags: native-american, apocalypse

I am in search of a difficult-to-Google fact. I once saw a Discovery Channel-esque documentary about an apocalyptic prophecy that all of the tools and other man-made objects would at some point take on a life of their own and turn on humankind. I'm pretty sure it was from a Native American culture (I thought Mayan but that didn't turn up anything useful online so maybe not).

Does anyone know whether this is/was a genuinely held cultural belief somewhere, if so what culture, and where I can find out more?

Comment: You mean, besides [Maximum Overdrive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_Overdrive)?

Comment: Not what I was after, but a very similar concept. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be referring to a legend in the [Huarochirí Manuscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huarochir%C3%AD_Manuscript) mentioned in this book: [Colonial Spanish America](https://books.google.be/books?id=Ww-J9Kjb2KgC&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=native+american+mythology+%22objects+coming+to+life%22&source=bl&ots=cfhVNzRk13&sig=ACfU3U3QEVj1Nm5FPY_NtaGsfu2OTystNg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiihvWf18fnAhXQjqQKHfIMAvoQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=native%20american%20mythology%20%22objects%20coming%20to%20life%22&f=false). Animate objects in this text are linked to a beginning-of-the-world event, the first sunrise, set in ancient times (which can of course also be considered an end-of-the-world event for the mythical time before the first sunrise).

An exhaustive study of this can be found in Linda Brown's [When Pre-Sunrise Beings Inhabit a Post-Sunrise World: Time, Animate Objects, and Contemporary Tz'utujil Maya Ritual Practitioners](https://www.academia.edu/12086525/When_Pre-Sunrise_Beings_Inhabit_a_Post-Sunrise_World_Time_Animate_Objects_and_Contemporary_Tzutujil_Maya_Ritual_Practitioners)

Comment: Thanks. Sounds very promising. Will have a look at that study!